# Date format conversion in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change dates by using VBA. The format that I have is `m/d/yyyy` (3/4/2021) or `mm/dd/yyyy` (03/04/2021). Excel recognizes the values as date.

I need to convert them to format `yyyymmdd`. There is no possibility to use Format cell->Custom.

Additionally, the dates should show date-1.

I started to write a code but faced some problems and I do not how to move forward with that.

```
Sub paydate()

Dim i as byte
Dim j as date
Dim k as string

i = 4

Do while cells(1,4)<>""
  j = cells(i,4).value
  cells(i,4).value=j-1
  j=cells(i,4)
Loop

End sub
```

To sum up, I created a loop to change the date to date-1, but I don't know to convert it to format `yyyymmdd`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing `Loop` to close your `Do While`

Comment: If you really really want to write a value that's not a date: `cells(i,4).Value = Format(j-1,"yyyymmdd")`.

Comment: @BigBen That is probably what I am looking for :) Thanks

Comment: @BigBen could you explain that?

Comment: @Gass, maybe try the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications).

Comment: @BigBen thanks for the link. `cells(i,4).Value = Format(j-1,"yyyymmdd")` works only for today's date right? The `j-1` I'm troubling understanding it.

Comment: That is because OP mentions "I created a loop to change the date to date-1".